# Order of requires in Asset Pipeline, Does it Matter?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

In my javascript `application.js` file I have the following

```
//= require search
//= require tutorial
//= require_self
//= require_tree .//message
```

Is there a problem with me putting `//= require_tree .//stock` after `require_self`? It looks like everything is working but I'm not sure of the implications of putting tree after self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that is doing is changing the order of where the javascript contained in application.js, if any, is concatenated with the rest of the assets.  If you have any code in application.js that is required in `search` or `tutorial`, then it will not work correctly.

You can read more about directive in the [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives).

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  order matters,  thats why jquery is always on top,  if you have any js that deppends on it,  it wont work